# Did the Prophet (s) proposed to Khadijah or Khadijah proposed to the Prophet?

Tags: nikah, prophet-muhammad

I was wondering if Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him and his household) proposed to Khadijah (as the request for the marriage) or Khadijah proposed to the Prophet (s)?

Note: Both Shia and Sunni view would be appreciated.

Comment: As you can find in wikipedia pages (Arabic, English, Spanish) ~ the same story about her marriage the major difference between sunni and shi'a is that sunni say she was a widow and had been married twice before marrying Mohammed (peace be upon him) and shi'a say that she was a virgin when Mohammed (peace be upon him) married her! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khadija_bint_Khuwaylid#Marriage_to_Muhammad

Answer (score 2):

As everybody knows, Khadija (radyia Allahu 'anha) had a very successful trade. She heard about Prophet Muhammad's nobel and wonderful characters, so she sent him with a trading caravan to Syria, accompanied by her slave, Maysara.

When the caravan returned,  Maysara told her even more about the Prophet and his success in trading. Khadija was then deeply moved and impressed and really wanted to propose to him but she didn't know how to express her thoughts to him.
So she sent one of her close friends, Nafisah bint Manbah, to the Prophet (PBUH). Nafisah asked him if she could ask him a personal question. The Prophet didn't object. So she asked him why is he unmarried till now. He told her because he didn't have financial resources. So she asked, will you be willing to marry a beautiful lady, from a noble family and wealth who is inclined to marriage with him. He asked about whom she's referring to. When she told him, he said he would be willing to marry her.

So his two uncles, Hamza and Abu Talib went to her uncle, and the formal proposal was made.

*So, we can conclude that the proposal was officially from the Prophet's side, but it was the will of Khadija to marry him and sending her friend to him, that motivated the proposal.*

Comment: uh-huh, it looks helpful. So as a consequence, the main proposal can be from Khadija side. (although the Prophet did it formally.) Well done for this proficient info. @Abdel Rahman.

Comment: This is definitely a Sunni perspective (at least that is how I know it has happened as a Sunni). _"he said he would be willing to marry her"_ --- a little detail at this point though: the Prophet (pbuh) didn't, and _logically_ and traditionally wouldn't make such an answer. According to Sunni view, after that point He (pbuh) discussed the matter with his uncle Abu Talib and Abu Talib felt a little shocked as woman's initiation of marriage proposal is not something common, especially, among the noble Arabs as the rank of Hadicha. Nevertheless, he blessed the unity and the story continues.

Comment: I personally think, as that's an event happened before the prophecy, one would have great deal of difficulty in locating reliable sources of how it actually has happened.

Comment: Jaszaka Allahu khayran for the extra detail. And yes, it was before Prpphecy. @ozbek

Answer (score 0):

As we all know that Hazrat Khadijah (RA) was a widow who was married twice before, and had three children. She was looking after her father's business. She was also looking for a trustworthy person who can help her in trade. She deployed Muhammad (S) to a trade visit, her servant, Masira, also accompanied him (S) on the trade visit. When Muhammad (S) returned in heavy profits, Masira spoke, "high at his personality", he said. Khadijah (RA) was so impressed that she herself sent a marriage proposal to Prophet Muhammad (S). His uncle had accepted the marriage proposal on Prophet's (S) behalf after consulting him. A while later they got married. This marriage proved very successful. Muhammad (S) was though only twenty-five, and Khadijah (RA) was forty years old when they got married. She bore him six children, two boys, who passed away in infancy, and four daughters which received a lot of love from Prophet (S). Muhammad (S) loved Khadijah (RA) a lot, he never got married during her lifetime.