# What's the proper way to ask someone for marriage?

Tags: nikah

I've just started looking into getting married and me being an introvert, it makes it really difficult for me to approach a ladies father and ask to marry his daughter.

According to prophet Muhammad (pbuh) or scholars, Hadiths etc.. what the proper way to ask a partner for their hand in marriage and also the dowry process.

Jazakallah Khairan.

Comment: Marrying requires a man . You man up and talk to the father .. good luck :)

Comment: Tell him , your status and education and tell him you want to be engaged with her . Show him how good you are , and your financial stability . Marketing yourself but with honesty , and then if she likes you while she is your fiance  , and they accept , you are lucky :)

Comment: Related: [Did the Prophet (s) proposed to Khadijah or Khadijah proposed to the Prophet?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28250/17163)